# AWK - Generating SN from ranges and adding it to record

Tags: text-processing, awk

Considering following comma delimited input file:

```
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154
```

Using `3rd` and `4th` fields from each record, I need to generate serial numbers with same other fields of the record that SN belong to.

for first record `(03 - 01 = 2+1)` This number of new records

for 2nd   record `(06 - 04 = 2+1)` This number of new records

Output:

```
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151,1
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151,2
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151,3
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154,4
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154,5
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154,6
```

Simply using `for` I can generate the SNs yet linking them to the original record is the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
awk -F, '{print; for (i = 0+$3; i <= $4; i++) print $0 FS i}'
```

Comment: Thanks, For why the zero in `i = 0+$3` ?

Comment: @Eng7, that's to convert the `03` to `3`. `0+$3` converts it to a number, and it's converted back to a string (but this time using the canonical integer representation) when printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
   printf '%s\n' "$l" | tee log
   for i in $(seq $(cut -d, -f3,4 log | tr , '\n')); do
     printf '%s,%s\n' "$l" "$i"
   done
done < input.csv

perl -F, -pe 's|(.*)\K|join $/, $,, map "$1,$_", 0+$F[2]..$F[3]|ex'  input.csv
```

output:

```
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151,1
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151,2
1,13/06/17,01,03,D151,3
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154,4
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154,5
2,25/06/17,04,06,D154,6
```

---

### Explanation

1. Current line saved into `$1`. The `\n` in the current record will not be saved into $1 as the `.` does not match a newline, unless the `/s` modifier is in effect.
2. `$F[2]..$F[3]` => generate a sequence of numbers starting from left ending with right, in steps of 1. The `0+` artifact is there to take away the leading zeros that otherwise would result.
3. `map` will perform the appropriate operation by combining the current line and the integer separated by a comma.
4. All these strings generated in Step-3 are joined together by the `$/` which is the `RS` and defaults to a newline.

Comment: [Seriously?](/q/169716)